# robots.txt: how are ill-formed disallow lines treated

Tags: robots.txt

What happens when a Disallow line includes more than one URI? Example:

```
Disallow: / tmp/
```

I white space was introduced by mistake.

Is there a standard way in how web browsers deal with this? Do they ignore the whole line or just ignore the second URI and treat it like:

```
Disallow: /
```

Comment: When reading the [`robots.txt` standard](http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html) very strictly, that space is part of the value of the field, because the same treatment is expected of the `User-Agent` line. I would consider it equivalent to `/%20tmp/`. However, other implementors might disagree. The standard is pretty shoddy.

Comment: Easiest way to verify is to simply use Google's webmaster tools and check their robots.txt parser/helper.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to a web server right now, and apparently that tool is designed to work with a domain, I can't just submit a robots.txt...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google, at least, seems to treat the first non-space character as the beginning of the path, and the last non-space character as the end. Anything in-between is counted as part of the path, even if it's a space. Google also silently percent-encodes certain characters in the path, including spaces.

So the following:

```
Disallow: / tmp/
```

will block:

```
http://example.com/%20tmp/
```

but it will **not** block:

```
http://example.com/tmp/
```

I have verified this on Google's robots.txt tester. YMMV for crawlers other than Google.